# ES6 Generator with $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use the ES6 generator on the client side with the Angular $http service. I'd like to be able to use the $http service without the use of callbacks, if possible. Like:

```
var gen = function* () {
    var test = yield $http.get('/test/');
    console.log(test);
};

var http = gen();
http.next();
http.next(); // returns undefined

/// or ///

var gen = function* () {
    yield $http.get('/test/');
};
console.log(http.next()); //returns a promise object which won't allow me to use the needed data
```

The reason why I ask is because I'm trying to mimic this demonstration https://youtu.be/QO07THdLWQo?t=4m58s

I'm just looking for the simplest, most straight forward approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: Generators don't magically know about promises. You need some runner to advance them asynchronously. Which library are you using?

Comment: It returns a promise. Generators don't handle the async nature

Comment: [What happens when promise is yielded in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33947850/1048572)

Comment: I'm just trying to follow a similar logic as the link above (I updated the post)

Comment: @muninn9: If you follow the video closely enough, he mentions that you have to use something like `smartCode`, `co`, `Promise.coroutine` or `Q.spawn`. You don't do those things. That stuff like `console.log(gen.next(…))` he left in his code does not work with yielding promises any more - he should have deleted it, it's confusing.

Comment: Yeah I went and checked out his source code which lays it out more clearly, hence the answer below. It took me a few times to finally wrap my head around this stuff. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One possible option is to wrap the generator function in Bluebird's Promise.coroutine like so:

```
//make sure Bluebird source code is included

Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    var gen = yield $http.get('/test/');
    console.log(gen.data);
})();
```

This has proven to be very useful in more complex applications and I hope others will find it useful as well. For that reason, I'm keeping this question up despite the down-votes. Here is a useful link on the subject:
https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/bf04432597334190bef4